# Indian citizen traveling from US to India via two Schengen countries

Tags: schengen, transit

I live in the US with Indian passport and I am traveling with a return ticket to India and my flight from US to India has two stops. My flight from Atlanta has a stop in Frankfurt and from Frankfurt to Amsterdam and from Amsterdam to Delhi. Everything is on the same reservation and traveling with KLM and its codes share flights. No airport changes either. I just want to make sure I don't need any transit visa for Frankfurt or Amsterdam

Comment: You need a visitor visa since you are entering the Schengen area proper. The flight from Frankfurt to Amsterdam is considered domestic and you will have to exit the international transit area.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to apply for a visitor visa of type C, not an airport transit visa.

Comment: The current accepted answer to the duplicate question, by Karlson, is incorrect, or at best imprecise and confusing.  The other answer, by Peter Green, is correct (this is consistent with @xngtng's comments here, but I want to call it out in the interest of reducing the potential for confusion).